# Upgrade of Jackson from org.codehaus.jackson to com.fasterxml.jackson (version 1.9.13 --> 2.9.8)

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

In our code we have org.codehaus.jackson imports in java file. now we are moving to com.fasterxml.jackson.

What are the points are to be considered for smooth up gradation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following are some of the changes identified between Jackson 1.9.x and Jackson 2.9.8
1. org.codehaus.jackson changed to com.fasterxml.jackson
2. org.codehaus.jackson.map changed to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind
3. SerializationConfig.Feature changed and spitted to SerializationFeature,MapperFeature
4. DeSerializationConfig.Feature changed and splitted to DeSerializationFeature,MapperFeature
5. AnnotationIntrospector.Pair changed to AnnotationIntrospectorPair
6. SerializationConfig.withAnnotationIntrospectro(...) changed to   SerializationConfig.with(...)
7. ObjectMapper.getSerilizationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(...) changed to ObjectMapper.addMixIn(....)
8. JSonSerialize.include changed to JSonInclude
9. ObjectMapper.readValue(JSonNode,...) changed to OjbjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.treeAsTokens(JSonNode),...)

Answer (score 8):

Upgrading from jackson-1.X to jackson 2.X

1. Update the dependencies from jackson-core-asl-1.X.jar and jackson-mapper-asl-1.X.jar to jackson-annotations.jar, jackson-core.jar, and jackson-databind.jar
2. Fix imports from **org.codehaus.jackson** to **com.fasterxml.jackson**
3. change the **get** method names to direct names

   **For Example:**

   **jackson-1.X methods:** getBooleanValue(), getFields(), getElements(), getIntValue()

   **jackson-2.X methods:** booleanValue(), fields(), elements(), and intValue()

Comment: I don't know who & why. Your post was interesting. I give you +1 for my part ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more point to @Ravi's Answer.

In jackson-databind-2.9.8, java.sql.Date by default will be serialized to numeric timestamp instead of [StdDateFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/util/StdDateFormat.html#_formatISO8601). This will specifically cause an issue when expected date format is StdDateFormat.

[Refer release notes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.9#javasqldate)

> java.sql.Date
>   As per databind#219 java.sql.Date will finally use same "timestamp-or-String" determination as java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar. This means that with vanilla, unchanged settings, values will be serialized as numeric timestamps. Note that the default String serialization will still default to java.sql.Date.String(), and not to default formatting java.util.Date uses.